# Time out error, probably infinite loop C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, space

The following code works 100% using Xcode, but when i run the code using the Autograder, i got the following error `Time out error, probably infinite loop C++`  as showing in the image below.

Does this means that my arrays are too small?

Input:

4 6

Women Conservatives Neocons Veterans

Trump Women 1

Trump Conservatives 1

Trump Neocons 5

Women Neocons 1

Neocons Veterans 5

Conservatives Veterans 1

**Output:**

8

**Here's My code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
/*map Group Name to a Integer
  useful for representation of graph
*/
map <string, int> nameToNumber;
/*
 adjacency matrix to represent graph
 this will work since number of nodes is less
  */
int graph[301][301];
/*
   recursion to find if target is reachable from src in graph
   par == parent of src.. useful to keep track of visited nodes
 */

bool reachable(int src, int target, int par = -1)
{
    if (src == target) return true;

    bool isReachable = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        if (i != par && graph[src][i] != 0 && reachable(i, target, src))
        {
            isReachable = true;
        }
    }
    return isReachable;
}

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    // add names to map
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        string name;
        cin >> name;
        nameToNumber[name] = i;
    }

    vector <pair<int, pair<int, int>>> edges;
    // input edges
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        string u, v; int w;
        cin >> u >> v >> w;
        edges.push_back(make_pair(w, make_pair(nameToNumber[v], nameToNumber[u])));
    }
    // sort edges based in increasing weights
    sort(edges.begin(), edges.end());

    int cost = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); ++i) {
        int u = edges[i].second.first;
        int v = edges[i].second.second;
        int w = edges[i].first;
    // check if u-v edge causes cycle

        if (!reachable(u, v)) {
            graph[u][v] = 1;
            cost += w;
        }
    }

    cout << cost ;

    return 0;
}
```

**Everytime i run my code using the Autograder i get the following error `Time out error, probably infinite loop`.**

[CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kuXP.png)

Comment: `string name; cin >> name;
nameToNumber[name] ` what is this?. you also use `std::getline()` for white spaces

Comment: so you are saying that it fails with some input data but not others. Do you know the input data to the timed out test cases. Also note that all your other test cases except 1 failed too

Comment: `vector > > edges;`. Does this even compile?

Comment: @Raindrop7 in the for loop i'm adding names to map

Comment: @pm100 This autograder was created by my professor, and i don't have access to these test cases.

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: As it stands this code does not even compile. This might have happened while copy-pasting or something. Please try to provide the code as you give it to the judge. You might also want to have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: so then try to imagine his test cases

Comment: @pm100 my professor mentioned to me that my arrays are too small hence the time outs

Comment: then you should use vector rather than fixed size arrays

Comment: but thats not going to cause time outs - it will cause crashes, timeouts happen becuase your recursion never ends for some reason

Comment: @pm100 i truly appreciate your time, how to make the the max number of vertices is 6000, this's one of the test cases

Comment: change graph to vector<vector<int>>